# opensource and fast html5 android SDK?

Tags: android, open-source

I am looking for a good android html5 mobile application SDK (using phonegap).  What it need:

- Fast and complete emulation (using browser or virtualization)
- Remote app preview using wifi (and NOT via USB), and android app is a must
- IDE is a must, I can use another one
- GUI is a must too

I found intel XDK, but it isn't opensource **and the emulator didn't support File API.**